# How to optimize Google Spreadsheet function execution time?

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets, optimization

```
function findAgentRow(){
  let row = 2;
  let emailCell;
  let maxRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  while(--maxRow){
    emailCell = sheet.getRange(row, findColumn(sheet, "Agent"));
    if(emailCell.getValue() == agentEmail){
      return row
    }else if(row == sheet.getLastRow()){
       return 0;
    }else{  
        row = row + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

I have written a google spreadsheets function that locates a row containing information about a person. It checks whether the row contains the person's email. The issue is that when the spreadsheet contains more than 700 rows the execution time is more than 2 minutes.

Is there a way to optimize it?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. `findColumn` declaration is missing. Also please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]. P.S. start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not to use `findColumn` in each loop.

You should also aim at using only one `getValues`.

```js
function findAgentRow(agentEmail) {
  // const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const row = 2;
  const col = findColumn(sheet, 'Agent');
  const values = sheet.getRange(row, col, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues().flat();
  return values.indexOf(agentEmail) + row;
}

function findColumn(sheet, value) {
  const row = 1;
  const values = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  return values.indexOf(value) + 1;
}
```